# Синонимизировать и объединить [google-firebase] и [firebase]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю [firebase](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase) сделать основной и объединить с [google-firebase](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-firebase).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Синонимизировано и объединено.